# How to get Facebook ad permalink using Facebook APi

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

When using ads manager, you can preview ad. There is also a hyperlink which goes *View post permalink with comments*. Is there any way to get that link using API

Comment: Also wondering this. I noticed for some types of pages you can do `https://facebook.com/{page_id}/posts/{post_id}` but that doesn't seem to work for community pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you must get the creative that's targeted by the ad.

```
$ad = new Ad($ad_id);
$ad->read(array(
    AdFields::CREATIVE,
));
```

Then get the info from the creative.

```
$creative = new AdCreative($ad->creative['id']);
$creative->read(array(
    AdCreativeFields::EFFECTIVE_OBJECT_STORY_ID,
));
```

Then `$creative->effective_object_story_id` will contain an ID that would look like xxxxxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyyyyy, where x is the ID of the page, and y is the id of the post/video/etc.
If you just go to https://facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyyyyy it should redirect you to the correct post

Hope this helps someone.